# Can Maven do this? Run selenium test, generate report, and then execute an jar file

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Currently I have a selenium test project, I am trying to automate this process:
1. run a selenium test
2. generate a report (surefire？)
3. and do some java code execution (jar)

Is it possible to do this by configuring them in maven?

I am new to maven, not sure if maven can do the job?

Comment: Yes. Start here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, maven will do that.  All you need to do is this:

```
1.  Run tests in the "test" phase of the Maven lifecycle.
2.  Generate a report.  If you are using Surefire with TestNG, in that case 
    TestNG automatically generates the report once you trigger its tests from
    the "test" phase.  If you need to post-process generate a report, then 
    you can create a "maven exec" task and bind it to the "verify" phase of
    the lifecycle.  One thing I do sometimes is generate HTML reports using a
    XSLT transformation using the xml-maven-plugin, triggered in the verify
    phase.
3.  I believe the 'package' phase will generally .jar your code up into a jar.  
    You can change that configuration to do what you need it to though. 
4.  Then, finally, create a "maven exec" task to run the .jar file at the end. 
    I think you could bind that to the "deploy" phase of the lifecycle.
```

Then, to execute that entire lifecyle, it is something like this:

```
mvn clean compile test-compile test verify package deploy
```

Comment: Some adjustments about the phases: the `package` phase is meant for bundling all kinds of resources to an artifact, e.g. a JAR. The `install` phase will copy this JAR to your local repository, `deploy` will upload it to a remote repository. You don't have to mention all phases, so when you call `mvn clean deploy` the effect will be the same. The first steps are easy to do with Maven, however: the third is a bit weird when talking about a build-lifecycle. It can be done and I would choose the `integration-test` or `verify` phase for binding.

Comment: Thanks, one more question,  can I run a specific class only in step 1?

Comment: also if i dont put the test classes in test folder, can i still run them?

Comment: No, test classes must be in the test folder.  You can override the "standard directory layout" though by configuring the test class location to be under the 'main' directory.  That would be a bad idea though.  I can't think of a reason why tests classes need to be in the main jar.